# ArcGIS Server REST get polygon centroid

Tags: arcgis-server, geoevent-processor

I have a Site reference feature service data in polygons served up by ArcGIS Server.  I need to get the centroid coordinate of a polygon by the Id but can’t find a method out of the box.

I’m working on a GeoEvent Processor Service that will use this Site service to grab a centroid from a site Id.  So far I believe my options are:

- Custom GP service, python – takes in polygon rings, returns point
- Server Object Extension – same as above
- Sql view, query layer served up as a feature service that uses [STCentroid](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933847.aspx) (The database uses a SQL GEOGRAPHY type) on the Site layer.  Would query the layer by ID to return the geometry.

The first two options keep me on track with a service orientated architecture however it certainly seems overkill to be writing an SOE for one function.  The final option could be a ‘goer’ but it means my logic is coupled to SQL Server.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what your question is. What are you trying to ask?

Comment: Be sure to use the edit button beneath your Question when clarifying it.

Answer (score 1):

I realised that the LabelPoints method over REST for ArcGIS Server Geometry service returns a polygon centroid (point) for an input Geometry.

This is more favourable than having a query at the database level.

Answer (score 1):

> "I need to get the centroid coordinate of a polygon by the Id"

First you'll need to get a reference to the polygon via its ID. You can do this with a [QueryTask](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/querytask-amd.html).

You'll then have access to the polygon's geometry, so you can use the [getCentroid](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/polygon-amd.html#getcentroid) method on the shape.

Answer (score 0):

There are several GeoEvent processors available on their GitHub gallery that allow you to extract a centroid.  [This one](http://solutions.arcgis.com/defense/templates/geoevent-extension/tools/processors/p2p/) is ready-compiled, supported, and can be downloaded and added to your GeoEvent (via GeoEvent Manager) to allow you to calculate centroids from polygons.

[image]